# PHP error: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: php, email

Hi I'm wrinting a simple mail script in PHP

- Of what that I found every one says its probably a whitespace in front of

But as you can see I can't find anything like the solutions on the internet in my code...

The error says : **output started at /customers/e/e/5//httpd.www/email.php:1)**

```
<?php
$to = '...@gmail.com';
$subject = $_POST['subject'];  
$message = $_POST['message'];  
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];  
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];  
$email = $_POST['email'];  
mail($to, "Contact www....com: $subject", "Gecontacteerd van de website: www.....com\nZender: $firstName $lastName\nBericht: $message", "From: $email");
header("Location:http://www.....com");  
exit;
?>
```

Comment: `<html>
<body>` is output that triggers sending the headers.... you can't have output before any additional `header()` in your script

Comment: As I remove the <html><body> It still doesn't work

Comment: So having edited your question.... what is line 3 of `email.php` because that's where the error is saying output was sent

Comment: Im using this page as action ? <form role="form" class="contact" method="post" action="../email.php">

Comment: I edited the file and remove the <html> and <body> and now the error refers to line 1. On this line I got the next code <?php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No output before sending headers

Functions that send/modify HTTP headers must be invoked before any output is made. Otherwise the call fails:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent (output started at **file:line**)

Some functions modifying the HTTP header are:

- [`header`](http://php.net/header) / [`header_remove`](http://php.net/header_remove)
- [`session_start`](http://php.net/session_start) / [`session_regenerate_id`](http://php.net/session_regenerate_id)
- [`setcookie`](http://php.net/setcookie) / [`setrawcookie`](http://php.net/setrawcookie)

Output can be:

- *Unintentional:*

  - Whitespace before `<?php` or after `?>`
  - [UTF-8 Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)
  - Previous error messages or notices
- *Intentional:*

  - `print`, `echo` and other functions producing output (like `var_dump`)
  - Raw `<html>` areas before `<?php` code.

**Hint :** for checking this, press **crtl+u** on the page to see the source, and check if the error is in line 2 , or there is a space before it.

Comment: I removed the <html> and <body> as I clear saw it wasn't needed here... But I still got this error ...

Comment: There is indeed a space before my error (if i check the page source), so what could cause this ?

Comment: check what file is called before calling the current file, maybe its in that file

Comment: how your script is being called? is it included in another file?

Comment: yeah in the file email.php as In my post on the top.

Comment: so check that file for any out put

Comment: I don't know what could cause any output. It's the code in my top post 'My question' thats all. This is the page http://daangeudens.be/email.php

Answer (score 0):

It's not just whitespace. You can't send any data at all to the client (i.e. anything outside `<?php ?>` tags) before you call `header()`.

What you need to do is move your PHP code to the top of the file, before any of the HTML code (although in this case it looks like you're not actually expecting any HTML output from this script anyway, so you can probably get rid of it entirely).

Comment: Yeah I removed the <html><body> but still getting the same error

Comment: Make sure there are no spaces or any other characters at all before the `<?php`.

Comment: Is PHP displaying any other errors/warnings/notices?