# Output a PNG image from a PHP include file

Tags: php, image

I have a include file called sign.php which has some code -

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
.....
imagepng($image_file);
.....
```

A file where I want to display this image - index.php

```
......
<what comes here?> include('../sign.php');
.....
```

How would I display it? Directly echo-ing it doesn't work!

Thanks.

MORE CODE:

sign.php

```
    .....
   {
    imagettftext($im, 22, 0, 240, 43 , $text_color, $font, $text_god);
    imagettftext($im, 22, 0, 241, 44 , $text_color, $font, $text_god);
}
imagettftext($im, 22, 0, 60, 42 , $text_color, $fontname, $text_username);
     imagettftext($im, 16, 0, 230, 72 , $text_color, $font, $text_kills);
imagettftext($im, 16, 0, 230, 102 , $text_color, $font, $text_deaths);
imagettftext($im, 16, 0, 230, 132 , $text_color, $font, $text_rwon);

imagettftext($im, 16, 0, 365, 72 , $text_color, $font, $text_alevel);
imagettftext($im, 16, 0, 365, 102, $text_color, $font, $text_dlevel);
imagettftext($im, 16, 0, 365, 132 , $text_color, $font, $text_rlost);
imagettftext($im, 16, 0, 365, 162 , $text_color, $font, $text_money);   // Prints the money in the picture. 

imagecopymerge($im, $skinImg, 505, 56,0,0,55,99,100);

header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($im); 

    imagedestroy($im);
```

index.php

```
    .......
    <?php echo '<img src="../signature/sign.php" />'; ?>
    .......
```

Still doesn't work!

EDIT:

index.php

```
            include('../signature/sign.php');

            echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + base64_encode($stringdata) + '">';
```

sign.php

http://pastebin.com/uz1U3V4R

Comment: echo '<img src="sign.php" />';

Comment: use plain img tag, src is path to php file

Comment: is sign.php accessible through the browser? I mean, if you manually enter the URL, does it display the image?

Comment: No actually - it doesn't, because it requires a variable from index.php!

Comment: Oh.. You didn't mention it in your question.. I'll edit my answer, check it out in a couple of seconds

Comment: [**cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624838/php-error-warning-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by/21624855#21624855)

Answer (score 3):

This happens because `imagepng` directly outputs the content of the image to the browser. 
You should save the content of the image into a variable like this in `sign.php`:

```
... 
imagecopymerge($im, $skinImg, 505, 56,0,0,55,99,100);  

ob_start();
imagepng($im);
$stringdata = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

imagedestroy($im);   
...
```

And then display it in your index.php like this:

```
<?php
    include('sign.php');
    echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($stringdata) . '">';
?>
```

Comment: Can you post some more code from index.php? @RajatPawar

Comment: @RajatPawar Can you check whether my new solution works?

Comment: I exactly did what you said, but it displays a lot of gibberish now! Something like - "�PNG  IHDR���G IDATx�l�ْ,Yv�����b��uk�.tChB�D %3��E�?�/���/���/4�d��PF� ���F�p���S�>�ao=xd� ���"

Comment: Sorry for being so naive - but again, the code you gave simply outputs '0'. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your index.php?

Comment: Posted in main question

Comment: + shoud be .
    echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($stringdata) . '">';

Comment: @RezaSh Thanks :) All this writing on several programming languages may be very confusing.. Edited my answer

Comment: Thank you ! Tons of love from here. Works. Thank you - Ephi Gabay, RezaSh, code360, Alireza and stackoverflow for such quick answers!

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src='< ?php echo 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents('img.png')) ; ?> '>


<img src='<?php include("img.png"); ?>
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

According that you said you tried `<img src='sign.php'>` and its not working, I guess something is wrong with set the header,Consider that

> #### No output before sending headers

Functions that send/modify HTTP headers must be invoked before any output is made.

Some functions modifying the HTTP header are:

- [`header`](http://php.net/header) / [`header_remove`](http://php.net/header_remove)
- [`session_start`](http://php.net/session_start) / [`session_regenerate_id`](http://php.net/session_regenerate_id)
- [`setcookie`](http://php.net/setcookie) / [`setrawcookie`](http://php.net/setrawcookie)

Output can be:

- *Unintentional:*

  - Whitespace before `<?php` or after `?>`
  - [UTF-8 Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)
  - Previous error messages or notices
- *Intentional:*

  - `print`, `echo` and other functions producing output (like `var_dump`)
  - Raw `<html>` areas before `<?php` code.

Comment: Thanks for answering - sign.php won't work directly as it uses a variable in index.php!